# Is Windows 7 on a SSD slower if I use Windows integrated mirroring?

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd, mirroring

Yesterday I configured Windows software mirroring for my SSD and one of my HDD, because I don't want to loose any data from the SSD. Now Windows seems to be much slower. Is mirroring in Windows 7 so slow that I use all my advantages that I had with the SSD?

Comment: If you have two HDDs mirrored, your read/write speed decreases to the slowest one. If you worry about the data in the SSD, then move the folder Mi Documents and your user data to the HDD, but leave the SO and programs in the SSD.

Comment: OK. Thanks for that information. There is no important data on the SSD, just 128GB of programs and I don't want to reinstall all of them if my SSD crashes. I think I will use a weekly backup or something like that, instead of mirroring then.

Comment: That'll be the best way to do it (weekly backup). Schedule "Create System Image" in Windows Backup and Restore - you can restore that image to a new SSD with pretty minimal hassle, and if you need anything from it in the meantime, it stores it as a VHD file (which you can mount in Win7-8 or browse in applications like 7zip).